# How to make navbar responsive while displaying the dropdown's menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am having trouble making my navbar responsive using Bootstrap. Instead of hiding the submenu lists, I want it to **display** and make it responsive as well. I just borrowed the logo of google because my logo has the same size with it. Once I shrink it, its not making responsive. Im using the `navbar-header`, `nav`, etc. classes of bootstrap but it doesn't work. Please see my code below for your review.

```css
ul.nav ul{
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

ul.nav li{
  list-style: none;  
}

.menu-header{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  padding-bottom: 3px;

}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom: 0;">

      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
         <img class="" src="https://www.google.com.ph/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png">
        </a>
       </div>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="">
         <a href="#">

         </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
         <div class="">
          <div class="menu-header">MENU1</div>
          <ul>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub1 of MENU1</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub2 of MENU1</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li class="">
         <div class="">
          <div class="menu-header">MENU2</div>
          <ul>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub1 of MENU2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub2 of MENU2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub3 of MENU2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub4 of MENU2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub5 of MENU2</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li class="">
         <div class="">
          <div class="menu-header">MENU3</div>
          <ul>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub1 of MENU3</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub2 of MENU3</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub3 of MENU3</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li class="">
         <div class="">
          <div class="menu-header">MENU4</div>
          <ul>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub1 of MENU4</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub2 of MENU4</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub3 of MENU4</a>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </div>
        </li>
       </ul>

       <div class="clearfix"></div>

       <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-login-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          ☻ Log In <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
           here
          </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary reg" href="#">◘ Register</a>
       </div>


      </div> <!-- End of Container -->

      <div class="fgol-header-line"></div>

     </div>
      
      
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain you exact issue? perhaps an image mock up of what you are trying to accomplish. It appears responsive to me.

Comment: Because if you view it in phone/tablet. it looks ugly, I mean MENUs should has dropdowns, but in phone/tablet only.

Comment: The device doesn't really matter its screen size. You can resize your browser so its small to mimic a small device. Are you trying to mimic what this site does when it gets smaller? http://www.boasecuritiessettlement.com/  Again you can check in your browser just resize it so the window is very narrow

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins Yes indeed. But that's not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you show in a image how it should look like.

I come up with my guess you were trying to achieve:

```css
ul.nav ul{
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

ul.nav li{
  list-style: none;  
}

.menu-header{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  padding-bottom: 3px;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom: 0;">

      <div class="container">
       <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainSubNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
         <img class="" src="https://www.google.com.ph/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png">
        </a>
       </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainSubNav">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MENU1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub1 of MENU1</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub2 of MENU1</a>
           </li>       
      </ul>
     </li>
     
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MENU2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub1 of MENU2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub2 of MENU2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub3 of MENU2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub4 of MENU2</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub5 of MENU2</a>
           </li>      
      </ul>
     </li>     
     
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MENU3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub1 of MENU3</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub2 of MENU3</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub3 of MENU3</a>
           </li>      
      </ul>
     </li>
     
     <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MENU4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub1 of MENU4</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub2 of MENU4</a>
           </li>
           <li>
            <a href="#">Sub3 of MENU4</a>
           </li>     
      </ul>
     </li>

       </ul>
</div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>

       <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="btn-group">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-login-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          ☻ Log In <span class="caret"></span>
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
           here
          </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <a class="btn btn-primary reg" href="#">◘ Register</a>
       </div>


      </div> <!-- End of Container -->

      <div class="fgol-header-line"></div>

     </div>
      
      
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Just for reference, [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z68z7b97/1/)

Comment: hm, I only want the `icon-bars` to display when in tablet or phone. but if in pcs, I want the sub menus to be displays as well as the MENU.

Comment: The only problem is to make the menus as dropdown when in phone/tablet

Comment: @Jonjie just did that easy fix, refer [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

Comment: Nice suggestion. I'm gonna try it later.

Comment: I got it now. I used your link. Nice